# In iMovie, can I suppress the visual portion of a video clip?

Tags: imovie

I'm using iMovie 10.1.12 on Mojave.  I have a video clip that I want to play at the beginning of my slideshow.  However, I only want the audio portion of the video clip to play and would like the screen to be black while the audio is playing.  What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the video and select "Detach Audio". From there you can delete the video portion and only be left with the audio.